# How to load the Second tab bar from the current tabbar

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I have table view controller inside a tabbarController .The problem is when I click when a row in tableView it does not load the second tab bar controller from the existing tab bar controller.

Here is my `didSelectRowAt` code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let storybaord=UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let tabBar=storybaord.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBar") as! UITabBarController

        let DVC = tabBar.viewControllers?[0] as! NewsViewController

        let image = sneakersnews[indexPath.row].image
        DVC.getImage = image
        let news = sneakersnews[indexPath.row].news
        DVC.getNews = news
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tabBar, animated: true)
    }
```

You can download the full code from this link:
link.https://drive.google.com/file/d/10w9MQaRxGlMSG_lK07N1c7nJWQLC8BWc/view

Answer (score 0):

You must present the new tabBar as a modal and not within the navigation controller that you have

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let storybaord=UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let tabBar=storybaord.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBar") as! UITabBarController

    let DVC = tabBar.viewControllers?[0] as! NewsViewController

    let image = sneakersnews[indexPath.row].image
    DVC.getImage = image
    let news = sneakersnews[indexPath.row].news
    DVC.getNews = news

    present(tabBar, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: 1-why the view controller are shown twice after selecting row from table view?                                                               2-Why the navigation bar not appear on second tab bar controller?

Comment: Why are you changing the flow, the new tabBar must also have a navigationBar, you are superimposing another viewController (TabBarController) on the current one

Answer (score 0):

Just after pushing UITabBarController you can set its selected index

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tabBar, animated: true)
 // when you want to open first index
   tabBar.selectedIndex = 0
   // when you want to open second index
   tabBar.selectedIndex = 1
```